# How to load sql database files instantly in python chatbot?

Tags: python, sql, database, python-3.x, bots

I have made a bot in **Python** using **Chatterbot module**.
It works fine but whenever I launch it, It starts training itself again that I already did.
I want that it loads the sql database file when it starts and dont train itself again and again it is very irritating need help....

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the part of training once you have trained your data.
For example:
below is a basic snippet to create and train a chatterbot.

```
chatbot = ChatBot("bot")
conversation = [
   "Hello",
   "Hai there !",]
chatbot.set_trainer(ListTrainer)
chatbot.train(conversation)
```

After training has finished you can remove this line.

```
chatbot.train(conversation)
```

You can either create a new file without the above line or you can apply some logic in the same code for not executing it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `read_only = True` parameter when you're creating the bot object.

```py
bot = ChatBot('Test', read_only=True)
```